# Tables not showing in database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, migration

I have already migrated the table, then added columns to it. Then again migrated it. But, it says

> Nothing to migrate

and, it doesn't even show my table, and it's columns. We three people are working on it and the database is hosted on another server.

When I try to rollback, it shows error:

> [ErrorException]
>     Undefined index: 2017_01_07_071008_create_user_detail_table

And this migration is created by my friend on her computer. 
What's the problem here, I don't understand.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another migration to [add columns to created table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns) and then run:

```
composer dumpauto
php artisan migrate
```

Or you can [recreate all tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#rolling-back-migrations):

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

In this case all data will be lost.

Comment: Did you create another migration and ran two commands from my answer? Or you've edited existing migration?

Comment: Hey, worked, Thank you. But can you please tell me, I tried dump-autoload even before, but it showed errors. Why did I have to delete the previously created migrations?